# Is Ramban's commentary on Hebrew Books?

Tags: jewish-books, ramban

I'd like to read Ramban's commentary on Devarim 4:2. Is there a PDF of it on Hebrew Books?

Comment: Have you tried to search it?
https://hebrewbooks.org/40235

Comment: Try halhatorah it's better. Entirely digitalized

Comment: @kouty It's even translated on Sefaria... https://www.sefaria.org/Ramban_on_Deuteronomy.4.2

Comment: @Kazibácsi I'm aware that it's on Sefaria. I'm looking for a PDF

Comment: Copy it to Word and press _print to PDF..._ :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find Ramban's commentary on Devarim 4:2 as a PDF, on Hebrew Books, here: https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9617&st=&pgnum=51

I finally found it! :D

Comment: A more direct link to the PDF of that page: https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpagefeed.aspx?req=9617&pgnum=51